# Add ListNavigationCallbacks on my Actionbar in Sherlock in Android?

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock

I am working on an application, using ActionBar of Sherlock Library. I want to add a List of items at the Right corner of  the ActionBar, that is, **ListNavigation in ActionBar**.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Getting a reference to action bar of this activity */
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        /** Set tab navigation mode */
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, 
                R.array.locations, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);

        /** Getting a reference to ViewPager from the layout */
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        /** Getting a reference to FragmentManager */
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();      

        /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {              
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);             
            }

        };

        /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

        /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        /** Setting the FragmentPagerAdapter object to the viewPager object */
        mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        /** Defining tab listener */
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {              
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
        };

        /** Creating Android Tab */
        Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Android")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.android)
                .setTabListener(tabListener);

        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        /** Creating Apple Tab */
        tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
                .setTabListener(tabListener); 
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);  
        tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple-2")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
                .setTabListener(tabListener); 

        mActionBar.addTab(tab);  
        tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple-3")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
                .setTabListener(tabListener); 
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);  

    }
}
```

1) but I am getting error in `mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);`  context this is not working here.

2)I am not getting how to popup the list on this button click.

3)Also, when i implemented these three line of code for Navigation List

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, 
                    R.array.locations, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
            mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
```

My Tabs got hidden. 
Please suggest me help me.

Answer (score 1):

1) Does your activity implement OnNavigationListener? It doesn't seem to be, and you're passing a reference to your Activity instance to setListNavigationCallbacks() which needs an OnNavigationListener.

2) I'm not sure what you mean by this button click.

3) Your tabs got hidden because you're specifying NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST as opposed to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS. You can only have one or the other as part of the ActionBar.

What you could do if you want both tabs and drop-down is use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST in the ActionBar, then have the Fragment within your activity contain a set of tabs. Have a look at the TabHost class.

Comment: My first 2 points got solved, thanks for the suggestions.
Just getting problem in 3rd point

Comment: I am implementing the ActionBar with Tabs.. So what I need to do to show both?

Comment: I have four classes, the first one that I have stated up. other then this I have MyFragmentPagerAdapter, Fragment1 & Fragment2 Class.

Comment: I have 4 classes in my application now. The first one is the MainActivity, that is stated up. The other 3 are MyFragmentPagerAdapter, Fragment1 and Fragment2.

Comment: You can't use 1 stackoverflow question for all your problems. Ask 1 question and create another if you have a separate problem.